# Почему не срабатывает ajax и не передается запрос?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

Это код для того что бы редактировать доп.поле не заходя в запись (в админке водпреса)
я не пойму почему не срабатывает вообще и не передается значение.

```
 // быстрый редактор в админ панеле по записям

   function true_add_post_columnd($md_columns){
    $slider = array( 'description' => 'Description' );
    $md_columns = array_slice( $md_columns, 0, 5, true ) + $slider + array_slice( $md_columns, 5, NULL, true );
    return $md_columns;
}
 function true_fill_post_columnd($dcolumns) {
    global $post;
    switch ($dcolumns) {
        case 'description':
            echo '<input type="text" class="this_description" data-id="' . $post->ID .'" value="' . get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'description', true ) . '" /><p></p>';
            break;
    }
}
 add_filter( 'manage_edit-page_columns', 'true_add_post_columnd', 10, 1 ); // manage_edit-{тип поста}_columns
 add_action( 'manage_pages_custom_column', 'true_fill_post_columnd', 10, 1 ); 



function updateDescription_callback(){ // название не имеет значения, но должно соответствовать названиям в хуках
    update_post_meta($_POST['page_id'], 'description', esc_attr($_POST['description_val']));
    die(); 
}
 if( is_admin() ) {
    add_action('wp_ajax_updateDescription', 'updateDescription_callback');
    add_action('wp_ajax_updatePrice', 'updatePrice_callback');
    // wp_ajax_nopriv_ не нужен, так как мы работаем в админке (а в админку не попадают незареганные пользователи)
}
```

вот js

```
jQuery(function($){

     $('.this_description').blur(function(){
        this_description = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:ajaxurl,
            data:'action=updateDescription&description_val=' + this_description.val() + '&page_id=' + this_description.attr('data-id'),
            beforeSend:function(xhr){
                this_description.attr('readonly','readonly').next().html('Сохраняю...');
            },
            success:function(results){
                this_description.removeAttr('readonly').next().html('<span style="color:#0FB10F">Сохранено</span>');
            }

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Проверьте консоль, если у Вас есть ошибки - отредактируйте ответ, добавив эти ошибки

Comment: @LazyTechwork неа нету ошибок, хотя я исходил из этого скрипта
https://misha.blog/wordpress/admin-ajax.html

Comment: `jQuery(document).ready(function() {` - так должна начинаться ваша функция. Если скрипт сработает раньше, чем браузер загрузит `$('.this_description')` то ничего работать не будет. Не на что вешать событие.

Comment: И что значит - не срабатывает вообще? Скрипт запущен (есть в dev tools?) Что во вкладке Network - выполнился запрос на сервер? Какой ответ? Вы заставляете гадать на кофейной гуще.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Да я все скопировал по ссылке ввыше, и тот код что у него на сайте у меня точно так же стоит и работает, но когда я пытаюсь подставить свои значения, то ничего не работает.

Comment: Я вам задал конкретные вопросы, на них стоит ответить, если хотите получить здесь помощь.

Comment: Вообщем в списке страниц выводится поле description, и в каждой строке этот скрипт выводит input в который нужно вводить "описание мета",  при смене фокуса на любую другую область экрана, этот input эмитирует ну или должен выполнять отправку, и возвращать ответ ввиде "Сохраняю..." но даже этого не происходит,  тоесть как будто аякс этот подключен не правильно, а вот в другом раздее в магазине на списке товаров там тоже стоит но меняется цена, и работает все как должно.

Comment: Я подозреваю что именно не правильно аякс работает. Может я ошибаюсь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение получилось таким, вероятнее всего где то ошибка была и методом тыка из за незнания php. Этот код позволяет редактировать доп.поля не заходя в редактор страницы, а прямо в колонке редактировать доп поля, в моем случаее это description.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
function true_fill_post_columnsdesc( $column ) {
    global $post;
    switch ( $column ) {
        case 'description':
            echo '<input type="text" class="this_desc" data-id="' . $post->ID .'" value="' . get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'description', true ) . '" /><p></p>';
            break;
    }
}

add_action( 'manage_pages_custom_column', 'true_fill_post_columnsdesc', 10, 1 );

function updateDescr_callback(){ // название не имеет значения, но должно соответствовать названиям в хуках
    update_post_meta($_POST['page_id'], 'description', esc_attr($_POST['description_val']));
    die();
}
if( is_admin() ) {
add_action('wp_ajax_updateDescr', 'updateDescr_callback');
    // wp_ajax_nopriv_ не нужен, так как мы работаем в админке (а в админку не попадают незареганные пользователи)
}
```

и js

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.this_desc').blur(function(){
        this_desc = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:ajaxurl,
            data:'action=updateDescr&description_val=' + this_desc.val() + '&page_id=' + this_desc.attr('data-id'),
            beforeSend:function(xhr){
                this_desc.attr('readonly','readonly').next().html('Сохраняю...');
            },
            success:function(results){
                this_desc.removeAttr('readonly').next().html('<span style="color:#0FB10F">Сохранено</span>');
            }
        }); 
    });

});
```

[Источник скрипта](https://misha.blog/wordpress/admin-ajax.html)

Answer (score 0):

А попробуйте прямо добавить onblur в input

```
function true_fill_post_columnd($dcolumns) {
    global $post;
    switch ($dcolumns) {
        case 'description':
            echo '<input type="text" onblur="update_description_ajax(this)" class="this_description" data-id="' . $post->ID .'" value="' . get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'description', true ) . '" /><p></p>';
            break;
    }
}


function update_description_ajax(self){
    this_description = $(self);
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:ajaxurl,
        data:'action=updateDescription&description_val=' + this_description.val() + '&page_id=' + this_description.attr('data-id'),
        beforeSend:function(xhr){
            this_description.attr('readonly','readonly').next().html('Сохраняю...');
        },
        success:function(results){
            this_description.removeAttr('readonly').next().html('<span style="color:#0FB10F">Сохранено</span>');
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)